# pytest not acknowledging PASSED dependency in base class results in SKIPPED tests in derived class

Tags: python, testing, pytest, tox, pytest-dependency

I have this little project where I use *pytest* and *pytest-dependency* with *tox* to develop integration tests on some code. Until now I used one base class (`BTestClass`) with some common tests in the root directory and the specific tests for each code component in a `test_Component.py file` next to it implementing a `TestC` class that inherits from `BTestClass`.

Everything worked fine until then. Now I want to add a `BTestClass2` for another set of components. So I added another layer of inheritance, but now it doesn't work, *pytest* validates the common `A` tests but then skips the tests that depend on it. I have no idea why.

Here's the filesystem layout:

```
λ tree /F
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is F029-7357
C:.
│   B.py
│   requirements-tox.txt
│   tox.ini
│
├───app_C
│   └───tests
│           test_C.py
│
└───common
        A.py
```

`common\A.py`

```py
import pytest


class ATestClass():

    @pytest.mark.dependency(name='test_a')
    def test_a(self):
        assert True
```

`B.py`

```py
import pytest
from common.A import ATestClass


class BTestClass(ATestClass):

    @pytest.mark.dependency(name='test_b', depends=['test_a'])
    def test_b(self):
        assert True
```

`test_C.py`

```py
import pytest
import sys


sys.path.append('.')
from B import *


class TestC(BTestClass):

    @pytest.mark.dependency(name='test_c', depends=['test_b'])
    def test_c(self):
        assert True
```

*pytest* output:

```
λ tox -- -rs
py38 installed: ...
py38 run-test-pre: PYTHONHASHSEED='367'
py38 run-test: commands[0] | pytest -x -v -rs
=============================================== test session starts ===============================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.8.1, pytest-6.1.1, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- ...\poc\.tox\py38\scripts\python.exe
cachedir: .tox\py38\.pytest_cache
rootdir: ...\poc
plugins: dependency-0.5.1
collected 3 items

app_C/tests/test_C.py::TestC::test_b SKIPPED                                                                 [ 33%]
app_C/tests/test_C.py::TestC::test_c SKIPPED                                                                 [ 66%]
app_C/tests/test_C.py::TestC::test_a PASSED                                                                  [100%]
============================================= short test summary info =============================================
SKIPPED [1] .tox\py38\lib\site-packages\pytest_dependency.py:103: test_b depends on test_a
SKIPPED [1] .tox\py38\lib\site-packages\pytest_dependency.py:103: test_c depends on test_b
===================================== 1 passed, 2 skipped, 1 warning in 0.14s =====================================
_____________________________________________________ summary _____________________________________________________
  py38: commands succeeded
  congratulations :)
```

Any idea why `test_b` is skipped and not executed?

Edit: If I make `BTestClass` standalone, removing `A` / `ATestClass` from the picture, it works fine.

```
collected 2 items

app_C/tests/test_C.py::TestC::test_b PASSED [ 50%]
app_C/tests/test_C.py::TestC::test_c PASSED [100%]
```

Comment: You seem to have the content of `test_C.py` in `common\A.py` - copy and paste error?

Comment: Yes, corrected, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `pytest-dependency`, a dependency on another test implies that that test runs before the dependent test. If that is not the case (in your example `test_b` is run before `test_a`, because `test_a` is located in a subdirectory), the test is just skipped. `pytest-dependency` doesn't do any reordering of tests (unfortunately).

If you cannot easily establish the order in which tests are run via naming, you may use the [pytest-ordering](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-ordering) plugin to bring the tests into the needed order. In your case you could do:

```py
class ATestClass:
    @pytest.mark.dependency(name='test_a')
    @pytest.mark.run(order=0)
    def test_a(self):
        assert True
...
class BTestClass(ATestClass):
    @pytest.mark.dependency(name='test_b', depends=['test_a'])
    @pytest.mark.run(order=1)
    def test_b(self):
        assert True
```

In this case, the tests are run in the order `test_a` - `test_b` - `test_c`, and all tests will run.

*UPDATE*:
You can also use [pytest-order](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-order/), which is a fork of `pytest-ordering`. If you use the pytest option `--order-dependencies` it will try to re-order the tests with dependencies created by `pytest-dependencies`, without the need to add extra marks.

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of that fork.